# jQuery tablesorter fancyNumber plugin not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am attempting to add a custom `fancyNumber` parser to tablesorter via [here.](http://lab.christianmontoya.com/jquery-tablesort-numbers-commas/)
However when I add the code to my page as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() { 
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "fancyNumber",
  is: function(s) {
    return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
  },
  format: function(s) {
    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat( s.replace(/,/g,'') );
  },
  type: "numeric"
});

} );
```

I then set my table headers as follows:

```
'<th class="{\'sorter\': \'fancyNumber\'}"><strong>Calls</strong></th>' +
```

I have to escape the single quotes as my table headers are wrapped up in a JavaScript variable.

However this does not work and my numbers with commas are still being sorted incorrectly:

```
Calls
783 
660
642,826 
613 
603,321
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if the metadata plugin was loaded. The sorter being set in the header as shown above requires the plugin.

Personally, I think a better method would be to set the sorter in the `headers` option:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
        3 : { sorter: 'fancyNumber' }
    }
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/282/) I set up to show that it works.